# java date and time from timestamp

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp, achartengine

I am working on android app with achartengine where I am making a TimeSeries linegraph. I have stored all my variables inside an Arraylist. Since I need correct date object to insert in the time axis of my chart I am using,

```
int count = list.size();
Date[] dt = new Date[count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    long a = Long.parseLong(list.get(i).get("time"));
    dt[i] = new Date(a);
}
```

Here `long a` has the timestamp . With above piece of code. I am able to get `dt` as `09-Apr-2014` but I need the date to be shown as `09-Apr 12:55` . How can I do that,

I tried using the folllowing

`SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm");
   Date now = new Date();
   String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);`

But Since strDate is a string I cannot use it as `dt[i] = strDate` which will throws an error as one is `Date` and another is `String`.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: _strDate is a String_  Please show an example of a date

Comment: I dont get your question. But if I correctly understood, then `Date[] dt = new Date[count];`  and `String strDate ` are obviously not of same data type. And since `strDate` will convert the timestamp to correct date format but it will be stored in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it this way:

```
dt[i] = sdfDate.parse(strDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really just need the date strings, you can do this:

```
int count = list.size();
String[] dt = new String[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    long a = Long.parseLong(list.get(i).get("time"));
    Date d = new Date(a);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm");
    dt[i] = dateFormat.format(d);
}
```

Or, if you actually need the Date array, just format the dates on the fly as you need them.

Comment: Well , actually you are correct if I need just my date in a String but, if you see my Question , on the second line I wrote ` I need correct date object to insert in the time axis of my chart` , so I clearly need just the date object not any String. And I stuck on the problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Well the question was about displaying the date and time in correct format. Might be I was unable to make you clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is misguided - you are showing how you create Date objects in the code, yet what you want to fix is how you show them.
The `Date` array will have dates precisely to the millisecond. The default `toString()` method of the `Date` objects shows only the day, that's why you're not seeing the time.
It is inherently the UIs responsibility to decide on the format of time that it is going to print, hence you should pass the Date array to the UI (or up to the point of printing) and format them there.

Comment: Well, you might be correct if I had to format and print the date, But since the achartengine don't always accept what I wrote, I need to match their criteria. I am showing the date as `09-Apr-2014` but I am unable to format the date to show `9 Apr 12:55` . So I come my question be misguiding.

Comment: In that case you might want to consider setting a different renderer, and either add labels yourself or configure this one. Which are you using now?

Comment: I am using `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`

Comment: I formatted the date as `dt[i] = sdfDate.parse(strDate);`  and `ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer,"dd-MMM HH:mm"); ` on the chart rendering side

Answer (score 3):

The DateFormat can do both (date to string representation and back):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
```

Date to String:

```
Date date = new Date();
String sDate = formatter.format( time );
```

String to Date:

```
Date date = formatter.parse(sDate );
```

When you store the date, you should store it as precise as possible (milliseconds). For displaying it as a string, you can use whatever format you want.